# Unable to add ckanext-ytp-comments to CKAN on Linux

Tags: ckan

While I try to install ckanext-ytp-comments on my CKAN installation on Linux, I followed steps mentioned in github https://github.com/yhteentoimivuuspalvelut/ckanext-ytp-comments1

After that while I click on a Dataset, it throws error "Server Error ‘An internal server error occurred’ "
I’m not sure what additional steps might be required for this installation.

My requirement is to allow users put comments against Datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-disqus extension that allows site visitors to comment on individual packages using an AJAX-based commenting system. It's easy to install and setup